# Possible to remove part of a rigid body bake?

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

very new to blender so forgive me if this turns out to be a dumb question.

I have a scene where I used a rigid body simulation of some falling objects interacting with some geometry, was very happy with the result and baked the simulation.

I want to add to this scene now. But to do that I want to remove part of the bake of ONE of the falling balls. So that I can then add a new rigid body simulation of this 1 ball so that it can interact with new geometry I'll add to the scene. The rest of the falling balls can keep their baked simulation as they happen to fall exactly the way I want them to.

Is there some way of doing this? I have the feeling that I can't remove part of a bake, but I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction on how to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two possible solutions here.

1. You can bake animation to keyframes, and then remove the part of the keyframes that you don't need.
2. Also, you can create a new object, that will use copy location / rotation / transformation constraints for mirroring baked transformations into a new object. Ones it is done, you will get the ability to set off this constraints by animation influence value from 1 to 0

Comment: I totally forgot about baking to keyframes.  
Would it be possible to then add that object to the rigid body simulation again? Say be keyframing the 'dynamic' toggle in the rigid body setting of the object. So that it keeps it's original animation but doesn't interact with the rest of the rigid body world until I 'flip the switch', making it dynamic and having it interact with new geometry?

Comment: In this case you should animate "animated" state